# Parsing: Is holding all tokens in a list a bad idea?

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, token, interpreter

In a recursive descent-parser with backtracking is it a bad idea to hold all of the tokens in a list? I read that it is a good approach unless we have an infinite number of tokens, but what if there is a big file and the number of tokens is big. Would that have any big effect on perfomance?

Comment: FWIW, usually the text representation of a program is bigger than the token list, so if you can load the source code fully into RAM, the token list should end up comparatively small. That said, if the code barely fits in RAM, even adding a single byte could make memory blow up. But while this can technically be an issue, I wouldn't say it's rarely one in practice. I'd wait with worrying about this until it actually becomes an issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't worry too much about it. If the file is so big that storing all tokens at once takes significant amounts of memory, then the abstract syntax tree will also take too much memory. More generally, you'll most likely need to have *some* representation of the whole file in memory sooner or later. Single-pass compilers aren't even possible for most modern languages, and the languages that go out of their way to enable a single-pass compiler (e.g., C) pay for it with a worse development experience.

Additionally, assuming we aren't talking about a C/C++ style preprocessor model, *reasonable* code files are smaller than a megabyte, meaning that even with a very space-inefficient token data type you're realistically looking at no more than a few dozen megabytes. Any larger file is pathological and the problem of the people writing such large files, not your problem.

Comment: You do need to consider the intended use of your language -- people don't write billion line C programs, but there are code generators that generate billions of lines of C code from some other more compact language.

Comment: @ChrisDodd C is a weird example, because compiling an C and C++ files of reasonable size *does* often entail tokenizing 100k+ lines of code from `#include`s. Also, modern C compilers aren't single-pass any more, so if you throw a literal billion lines of code at them, they will literally consume gigabytes of memory.

Comment: @delnan:  and, if you are daily compiling billion line C programs,  that won't be a problem, because you bought a PC with tens of GB of RAM to do this on and your credit card hardly noticed.  (I've seen million line C source files [yes, machine generated], but I've never see a billion line one).

Answer (score 1):

I'm in general agreement with @Delnan.   In any case, most compilers run on machines that have vast amounts of memory compared to the size of the program being compiled, so space isn't an issue.

I'd make the additional observation that *if* you are going to store the full AST, you are essentially storing the token list anyway, as the leaves of the AST.

That suggests a direction: don't store the full token list by itself.   Simply plan on using the AST leaves as a representation of it.